# Use WinForms code for driver using Win API

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, winapi, driver

I am looking into making a Windows driver and am trying to make a decent looking GUI. My question is, can I convert or use code from a winForms project for my driver. To be clear, I am not trying to have a separate application render a GUI and communicate any inputs to the driver, I purely want the driver to render the GUI.

If anyone knows how this can be done. Please let me know!

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: That can't be done. Drivers don't run in the same layer as user code, and can't directly display a UI, which is why no driver does what you're asking to do.

Comment: You need to have an executable running in user-mode and communicating with the driver.

Answer (score 1):

.NET languages are not usable in the kernel, that being said drivers do not ever perform their own UI operations (not even display driver management). UI is performed strictly by user-mode code. So that being a given it is perfectly possible to write a .net program that performs communication with a driver, although it will likely be painful compared to doing so in a native application.